# Background color to shrink into the border and the text inside it to grow upon hovering on it

Tags: html, css

I am new to `css` and `html`, I created the following code:

**Demo:**

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

#box {
  border: 10px dashed;
  black;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background: orchid;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack_css/stack.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <div id="box">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Amet.</p>
  </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want the `background-color` inside the `border` to shrink inside the border and the text inside it to grow to `larger` when the `<div>` is on hover. I tried using `@keyframes` and animations but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated and sorry if my question is stupid or irrelevant, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `css` transitions to increase the `font-size` of the text and to set the `border-clip` attribute to `padding-box`:

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

#box {
  border: 10px dashed black;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background: orchid;
  background-clip: border-box;  
  transition: background-clip 3s, font-size 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#box:hover {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack_css/stack.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<div id="box">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Doler Amet.</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Explanation:-

I created `css` transitions to do the required changes upon hovering on the `<div>` element which has the Id `#box`

The `background-clip` property defines how far the `background-color`(or even image) should extend within an element. The `padding-box` value sets the background to extend to the inside edge of the border.

For more information: [CSS_Background-Clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_background-clip.php) and
[CSS_Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)